# Sqlite behaves oddly in frozen Python script

Tags: python, sqlite

Using sqlite in Python3.6 and py2exe in Windows 10.

My python file which uses sqlite runs fine normally.
But when I convert to exe with py2exe I get a strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dsn2bom.py", line 1026, in <module>
File "dsn2bom.py", line 957, in doall
File "dsn2bom.py", line 705, in insertVariantBOM
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`
```

The python code immediately prior to this is:

```
qstr = f'CREATE TABLE "{varname}" AS {sqlstr}'
```

where sqlstr is a big `SELECT` statement, shown at the end of this question.

So the error is somewhere in the SELECT statement.  Fine I guess, but why is this different between the regular .py file and the version embedded in the .exe after running through py2exe?

Most of the debugging techniques in the sqlite page are about interactive debugging from the sqlite command line, which is not applicable here.

Full create table command.  I left all the comments in as this smells like some weird parsing error, character encoding issue, etc., that maybe happens with py2exe.  I don't think there is inherently anything wrong with the sql.

```
CREATE TABLE "845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" AS SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REFDES COLLATE natsort) Item,
       GROUP_CONCAT(REFDES) REFDES,
    CASE -- show PART_NUMBER if MPN available, else non-MPN-OPN, etc.
        WHEN CIS.CISMPN NOT NULL THEN CIS.PART_NUMBER
        --WHEN CIS.Description NOT NULL THEN 'Non-MPN Part Number'
        WHEN CLEANNLB.PART_NUMBER = 'DNP' THEN 'Do Not Populate'
        --ELSE CLEANNLB.PART_NUMBER --|| ' INVALID'
        ELSE ' INTERNAL ERROR'
    END PART_NUMBER,
    COUNT(CLEANNLB.PART_NUMBER) QTY,
    CASE
        WHEN CIS.CISMPN NOT NULL THEN CIS.Manufacturer
        --WHEN CIS.Description NOT NULL THEN CIS.Manufacturer
        WHEN CLEANNLB.PART_NUMBER = 'DNP' THEN 'Do Not Populate'
        --ELSE 'INVALID PART NUMBER'
        ELSE 'INTERNAL ERROR'
    END Manufacturer,
    CASE
        WHEN CIS.CISMPN NOT NULL THEN CIS.CISMPN
        --WHEN CIS.Description NOT NULL THEN CIS.CISMPN
        WHEN CLEANNLB.PART_NUMBER = 'DNP' THEN 'Do Not Populate'
        --ELSE 'INVALID PART NUMBER'
        ELSE 'INTERNAL ERROR'
    END "Manufacturer PN",
    CASE
        WHEN CIS.CISMPN NOT NULL THEN CIS.Description
        --WHEN CIS.Description NOT NULL THEN CIS.Description
        WHEN CLEANNLB.PART_NUMBER = 'DNP' THEN 'Do Not Populate'
        --ELSE 'INVALID PART NUMBER'
        ELSE 'INTERNAL ERROR'
    END Description,
    CASE
        WHEN CIS.CISMPN NOT NULL THEN CIS.Value
        --WHEN CIS.Description NOT NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN CLEANNLB.PART_NUMBER = 'DNP' THEN 'Do Not Populate'
        --ELSE 'INVALID PART NUMBER'
        ELSE 'INTERNAL ERROR'
    END Value
    FROM
    (
    -- This is the main query.  Get all PART_NUMBERs that will appear
    -- in output, even if DNP
    -- Start with original bom
    SELECT NETLISTBOM.REFDES, NETLISTBOM.PART_NUMBER FROM NETLISTBOM
        EXCEPT -- Remove parts that will have its OPN replaced by variant
            SELECT REFDES, PART_NUMBER FROM NETLISTBOM
            JOIN VARIANTS USING(REFDES)
            WHERE VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" != 'DNP' AND
                  VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" != 'POPULATE'
        EXCEPT -- Remove parts that will be DNP from variant
            SELECT REFDES, PART_NUMBER FROM NETLISTBOM
            JOIN VARIANTS USING(REFDES)
            WHERE VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" = 'DNP'
        EXCEPT -- remove primitive OPNs that are DNI
            SELECT REFDES, PART_NUMBER FROM NETLISTBOM
            JOIN DNI_PRIMITIVES USING(REFDES)
        EXCEPT -- remove instance OPNs that are DNI
            SELECT REFDES, PART_NUMBER FROM NETLISTBOM
            JOIN DNI_INSTANCES USING(REFDES)
        UNION -- Add variant parts back in using variant OPN value instead
            SELECT REFDES, VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" FROM NETLISTBOM
            JOIN VARIANTS USING(REFDES)
            WHERE VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" != 'DNP' AND
                  VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" != 'POPULATE'
        UNION -- add DNI instances back in as either DNP, original OPN, or new OPN
              -- if variant for this entry is NULL, then entry is present in BOM output as DNP
              -- if variant for this entry is anything else, then entry is present in BOM output
            SELECT REFDES,
            CASE
                WHEN VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX"='POPULATE' THEN NETLISTBOM.PART_NUMBER
                WHEN VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX"='DNP' THEN 'DNP'
                WHEN VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" IS NOT NULL THEN VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX"
                ELSE 'DNP'
            END PART_NUMBER
            FROM NETLISTBOM
            LEFT JOIN VARIANTS USING(REFDES)
            JOIN DNI_INSTANCES USING(REFDES)
        UNION -- add DNI primitives back in if POPULATE
            SELECT REFDES, PART_NUMBER
            FROM NETLISTBOM
            JOIN VARIANTS USING(REFDES)
            JOIN DNI_PRIMITIVES USING(REFDES)
            WHERE VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" = 'POPULATE'
        UNION -- Add DNP parts from variant back in with 'DNP'
            SELECT REFDES, 'DNP' FROM NETLISTBOM
            JOIN VARIANTS USING(REFDES)
            WHERE VARIANTS."845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" = 'DNP'
        UNION -- Add + parts
            SELECT SUBSTR(REFDES,2), "845-02368-01 PCBA, LEVEL SHIFTER, PROX" FROM VARIANTS
            WHERE VARIANTS.REFDES LIKE '+%'
     ) CLEANNLB
 LEFT JOIN CIS USING(PART_NUMBER)
 WHERE PART_NUMBER NOT NULL AND
       ((PART_NUMBER = 'DNP') OR
        (CIS.CISMPN NOT NULL AND CIS.Description NOT NULL))
 GROUP BY REFDES
```

Comment: Why are you using f-string with sql and not query params?

Comment: I have a simple mind.  I have no idea what that is and my brain is pretty full with 1000 other things.